# Reading/Writing Header Strings and Numerical Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm really new to Python and I'm unable to do something really simple.  I see examples here for dealing with strings and numbers, but not how to deal with one character-string header of a few rows followed by arrays of numbers.  I've found a partial solution, but the first row of data is partly chopped off.   This is what I've done:

```
import numpy as np
infil="infile.txt"
outfil="outfile.txt"
fi = open(infil,"r") 
fo = open(outfil,"w")
lines = fi.readlines()
fo.writelines(lines[0:3])
fi.close()
x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7 = np.loadtxt(infil, skiprows=3, unpack=True)
# Some computations with those columns of numbers occurs here.
data = np.array([x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7]
data = data.T 
np.savetxt(outfil, data, fmt='%f')
fo.close()
```

The above almost works too.   It's just that the first half of the
first row of data is missing.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Bill

Comment: You should also include a snippet of `infile.txt` so that we can see what the data looks like.

Comment: Good point.  I present the sample lines below.   I use \n to represent a new line in the input file.

// number of line : 1215\n
// v : 512.0\n
 x1      x2        x3               x4            x4       x5       x6             x7 \n
73156.727567363 23982.109 0.000000000 0.0 -0.0009 31.353455648 128.485\n
73188.081023010 23863.683 0.000000000 0.0 -0.0006 31.303370255 128.225\n
73219.334307873 23745.635 0.000000000 0.0 -0.0008 31.303370255 128.170\n
73250.687763521 23627.209 0.000000000 0.0 -0.0006 31.303370255 128.115\n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to add a maybe more elegant solution:
`np.savetxt` accepts a header string that is written to the file prior to the data. With this you really don't need that temporary file:

`np.savetxt(filename, data, header="my header\nand a second line")`

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, it does indeed make sense that savetxt would have that option.  A more elegant solution awaits....

Comment: Okay, I've finally gotten around to trying out the solution you suggest.  It creates a header where each line starts with "# " and there's an extra blank line (also preceded by "# ").   I want none of that.   So my three-line header needs to be written out with the following: np.savetxt(outfil, data, fmt='%f\t', header=h1+h2+h3.rstrip('\n'), comments='')    That writes out the header that I want, immediately followed by the lines of data.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: OK, I didn't realize you don't want the header to be marked. If it works for you, you might want to consider marking my answer as the accepted one

Comment: Yes, I agree: your answer should be the accepted one.  I'm not sure how to mark it that way though.  Okay... I found it...

Answer (score 0):

Yes!  Solved it!  Although the solution is INelegant.  The problem was to have an output file with many rows of properly formatted data following 3 rows of header.   The first 1.5 rows of data were cut off with the algorithm above.  The solution I give below does work, but it's not elegant because I use a temporary file to pass the formatted data rows to strings that I write to the final output file.   Any suggestions for improving and refining this algorithm are appreciated.  Till then, this works just fine.

```
import numpy as np              # Load useful routines for arrays. 

infil="infile.txt"              # Input file name.
tfil ="tmp.txt"                 # Temporary file name.
outfil="outfile.txt"            # Output file name.

fi = open(infil,"r")            # Open input file.
ft = open(tfil,"w")             # Open temporary file for writing into. 
fo = open(outfil,"w")           # Open output file.

lines = fi.readlines()          # Read in the input file.

fi.close()                      # Close input file.




x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7 = np.loadtxt(infil, skiprows=3, unpack=True)
                            # Read in and unpack the numerical arrays   from the input file. 

 # Computation with those numerical arrays will occur here when I'm ready.                              


data = np.array([x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7])
                            # Pack the data arrays together.

data = data.T                   # Transpose the data into columns.


np.savetxt(tfil, data, fmt='%f\t')        # Write to temporary file. 


ft.close()                      # Close temporary file. 

ft = open(tfil,"r")             # Now open temporary file to read in the formatted data lines.

dlines = ft.readlines()         # Read in the temporary file.

fo.writelines(lines[0:3])       # Write the header to the output file.

fo.writelines(dlines)           # Write the formatted data lines to the output file.

fo.close()                      # Close output file.
```